# Check status of processes by signals in C

Tags: c, process, signals, pid

I am trying to check an arbitrary process if it is running (State S) or not. If it is stopped (State T) then I should be wake it up and wait for it to terminate. So far, I am able to do this.

My question is, when I am waiting it to finish, I open a new terminal and stop that process with `kill -STOP <PID>` but waiting continues.

I do waiting by:

```
while((check = kill(PID,0)) == 0);
```

However, it turns out that this just checks whether a process exists or not. Is there a way to wait for an arbitrary process like this? But, wait only for running state.

Comment: What OS are you wanting this for?

Comment: `waitid()` might be of interest, btw.

Comment: @shawn i am using Ubuntu, waitpid() is for child processes but i am not aware of waitid() i am gonna check. And Mark, I do not want to continue in this while loop, which purpose do you think that this is a solution?

Comment: Sorry, I should have said *possibly* want to use `while((check = kill(PID,SIGCONT)) == 0);`  instead of *probably*, since I don't know your exact conditions.

Comment: Here's the reasoning for my suggestion: if you're going to have a loop that runs until either the process stops (in which case you continue it with SIGCONT and resume the loop) or exits (in which case you stop looping), it may be cheaper to just send SIGCONT in a loop. With a small delay in the loop so you don't burn up cpu time unnecessarily. The `kill` will get an error when the target process exits. If you only need to continue the process one or a few times, it may be cheaper to loop repeatedly reading and parsing /proc/nnn/stat or /proc/nnn/status until you see state T.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick dude I tried to read detail in /proc/pid/stat but permission denied error occurs.

Comment: @HARUNSASMAZ I'm not sure why stat files are unreadable for you. I just installed Ubuntu 18.04 and they're readable by me, a non-root user. Maybe you have some security module enabled. Can you read the /proc/nnn/status files?